# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors computation (in infinite dimension)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be the backward shift operator: $Tv = T(v_1,v_2,....) = (v_2,v_3,....)$. I would like to determine all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. So far I have the following:

1. It is evident that $(\alpha, 0,0,....)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$.
2. It is also easy to see that $(\alpha, \alpha, \alpha, ...)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$.
3. Finally I observed that if $\lambda$ is any scalar in the underlying field then $(1,\lambda, \lambda^2, \lambda^3,...) , (\lambda, \lambda^2, \lambda^3,...)$ etc. are all eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Now I need to either argue why these are all eigenvectors or find more. But although I think these are all I don't know how to prove it. How to proceed from here?

Comment: Suppose $Tv = \lambda v$, that is $0 = Tv - \lambda v = (v_2 - \lambda v_1, \, v_3 - \lambda v_2,\, \dotsc)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh right. So there are three different eigenvalues each with one corresponding eigenvector? Sort of hard to believe given that the space has infinitely many dimensions.

Comment: Duh. That was a stupid comment: there is in fact one eigenvector for every $\lambda \in \mathbf F$. Though, if $\mathbf F$ is a finite field there are still only finitely many eigenvectors while the whole space has infinite dimension.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $v$ satisfies

$$0 = Tv - \lambda v = (v_2 - \lambda v_1, v_3 - \lambda v_2, \dotsc, v_{n+1} - \lambda v_n, \dotsc),$$

then $v_{n+1} = \lambda v_n$ for all $n$, and hence $v_n = \lambda^{n-1}\cdot v_1$. Conversely, if we have $v_n = \lambda^{n-1}\cdot v_1$ for $n \geqslant 2$, then $Tv = \lambda v$, and either $v = 0$ (if and only if $v_1 = 0$) or $v$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Therefore all eigenspaces are one-dimensional, a basis for $E_\lambda$ is $\{g^{(\lambda)}\}$ with $g^{(\lambda)}_n = \lambda^{n-1}$.